# Datadog: ERROR:ddtrace.writer:cannot send services to localhost:8126: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, datadog

My application is running in the docker container and it is not able to communicate with dd-trace agent running on host which is ec2

I've done all the configurations and still facing `ERROR:ddtrace.writer:cannot send spans to localhost:8126: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to access `dd-trace agent` on host from a container:

**1.** Only on `<HOST_IP>:8126`, if docker container is started in a bridge network:

```
docker run -d <image_name>
```

`dd-trace agent` should be bound to `<HOST_IP>` or `0.0.0.0` (which includes `<HOST_IP>`).

**2.** On `<HOST_IP>:8126` (if `dd-trace agent` is bound to `<HOST_IP>` or `0.0.0.0`) and `localhost:8126`, if docker container is started in the host network:

```
docker run --network host -d <image_name>
```

As you already try to reach `dd-trace agent` on `localhost:8126`, so the second way is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nickolay.  if i added --network host i'm getting this error 
`docker: Error response from 
daemon: Conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior.`